# How do I check Windows 10 Version before launching the program?

Tags: windows

hey I was wondering is it possible to check what version of windows 10 the user is on, since my program only works on 1803 - 1909 thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Press **[Windows] key + [R]** to open the “Run” dialog box.
2. Enter cmd and click **[OK]** to open Windows Command Prompt.
3. Type systeminfo in the command line and hit **[Enter]** to execute
   the command.